# (typescript) Throw an Unexpected token when load local json file

Tags: json, typescript

I have a config file written with json, like:

```
{
  "example": "example"
}
```

I read this file in my typescript like:

```
var events = require('json!./example_file.json');
```

Finally I got the Unexpected token:

```
index.html:18 Error: (SystemJS) Unexpected token :
    example_file.json:2
      "example": "example"
               ^
    SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
        at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:76:16)
```

When I remove the double quotes from the key, the script will run correctly. But how can I read the JSON file with standard JSON format? I don't want remove the quotes.

Thanks!

Comment: Seems like you are using SystemJS. Are you using the [json plugin](https://github.com/systemjs/plugin-json)?

Comment: yes, I'm using systemjs for version 0.19.39.

Comment: But are you using the json plugin?

Answer (score -1):

there's a article about that here: https://hackernoon.com/import-json-into-typescript-8d465beded79
Just add

```
declare module "*.json" {
    const value: any;
    export default value;
}
```

to your typings.d.ts config file and use `import` to read your json file